# Tabs automatically from list

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs

Excel 2007: I need to make tabs automatically and place the tab name in a cell on each new tab.  What I have below, from a command button,  will make the new tab. How can it read from a list of names and automatically create a tab with the name in cell B3 on each tab?

```
Private Sub CmdNewTAB_Click()
Worksheets("FocusAreas").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'Active.Sheet.Name = NewSheet.Value
'Tab name in B3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is a value of items within an excel worksheet, and you want to add tabs based on that list, you COULD do something like this:

```
Sub Readinto_array()

On Error Resume Next
Dim arrData() As Variant
arrData = Range("D5:D9").Value

For Each cData In arrData
    If cData <> "" Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = cData
        Worksheets(cData).Range("B3") = cData

        End If
Next cData
End Sub
```

**Assumptions for the above**:

1. List of names is on same worksheet as the button.
2. List is on same workbook as the button.

The `Worksheets(cData).Range("B3") = cData` is the part that adds the worksheet name to the new sheet in cell `B3`.

If you can specify where your list is located in a simliar manner; if it's not on the same sheet as the button, then specify the proper value in the `arrData = Range()` portion of the VBA file, such as:  `arrData = Worksheets("SourceSheet").Range("D5:D9").Value`.

Comment: This is spot on.